# Openshift gear size and increasing Xmx

Tags: java, tomcat7, openshift, heap-memory, newrelic

**Background:**

In Openshift, I am using 3 small gears each with 512m. The app has a web load balancer added to it. The web app is a tomcat 7 based app deployed with jbossews-2.0

**Question 1**: I read somewhere that a web load balancer will itself run in a gear. So does that mean, for scaling I have only one more gear left? Considering 1 gear in which the tomcat instance runs, 1 where load balancer run and in case load increased ill have the last one gear out of 3 to scale?

**Question 2**: Documentation says that each gear comes with 512m. I have configured New relic with my tomcat 7 app. I am seeing the following jvm configurations set :

```
-XX:MaxPermSize=102m, -XX:MinHeapFreeRatio=20, -Xms40m, -Xmx256m
```

Now if I have 512m available, am I right in thinking that I can increase the max heap to somewhat greater maybe -Xmx384m or maybe the complete 512m ?

**Question 3**: If yes, how to do so? I have added action hooks that indeed set the arguments but the environment settings in new relic still shows the max heap as 227m. In the provided list of arguments I see two arguments, one is my custom xmx and one comes by default

```
-Xms40m, -Xmx256m, -Xmx384m,
```

It seems that jvm picks the first arguments it finds which i am not sure why its not getting updated by my custom arg. To set this is what I did in my pre hook

```
export _JAVA_OPTIONS="$_JAVA_OPTIONS -Xmx384m -javaagent:/var/lib/openshift/{###}/app-root/repo/newrelic/newrelic.jar"
```

also tried

```
export JAVA_OPTS="-Xmx384m $JAVA_OPTS"
```

Please guide so that my custom xmx argument is only read instead of default.

Answer (score 0):

**Question 1:**
*copied from https://developers.openshift.com/en/overview-platform-features.html#how-scaling-works*

> The first web gear in a scaling application has HAProxy installed, but also your web application. Once you scale to 3 gears, the web gear that is collocated with HAProxy is turned off, to allow HAProxy more resources to route traffic. Here’s a [diagram](http://openshift.github.io/documentation/oo_system_architecture_guide.html#horizontal-scaling) of your scalable app. If you scale down back to 2 gears or less, the web cartridge on your first gear is started again.

**Questions 2 & 3**
You can increase the heap size however, you have to essentially reset all the existing `JAVA_OPTS` along with your new `-Xmx` value. So next time use the `JAVA_OPTS` env variable and set your heap size, then be sure to copy the rest OPTS from https://github.com/openshift/origin-server/blob/master/cartridges/openshift-origin-cartridge-jbossas/versions/7/bin/standalone.conf#L136.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can actually change the options as they are set by the cartridge/gear size combination, and because JAVA_OPTS is controlled by openshift. Anyway, you have to use JAVA_OPTS_EXT instead and that's limited to some extra params like system properties, garbage collector, etc.